# Flutter FirebaseMessaging token not registered error

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application using firebase push notification written in Flutter. Until a few months ago firebase messaging was working fine.

But now when I send a notification in **postman** to the **token** I got with the `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()` method, I get the `NotRegistered` error.

> I get a different token every time I restart the app. As far as I
> know, this token should change without uninstalling the app from the
> phone

> Notifications work fine on the android side of the same project

Solutions I tried

- I updated the certificates.
- I updated `firebasecore` and `firebase_messaging` packages to the latest version
- I completely uninstalled and reinstalled the app
- I replaced the ios folder of my flutter project with the code of the previously working version

The `app` information here is completely accurate

```
  var app = await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();
  var token = FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  print("Token $token");
  // c7YPa5Jb2kcBqHVkmFE8HO:APA91bFxwGYywZi-Q20oC1l1t6KU3iDaB9JtK58Da2UyNpx88SXUgMc0vZIv7ExnUlmH4kh-AbRPmhL0AYdrmeJ_W7XYMxbXbI_uWzkSLDKZYtH_ll53LONxz2ETPVma0W1xetQOBKtL
```

Postman reguest

[image]

Xcode

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the [documentation of the `fcm/send` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), the conditions that cause this error are given, but **in my case everything seems to be correct**

> An existing registration token may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:
>
> - If the client app unregisters with FCM.
> - If the client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if the user uninstalls the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNs Feedback Service reported the APNs token as invalid.
> - If the registration token expires (for example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens, or the APNs token has expired for iOS devices).
> - If the client app is updated but the new version is not configured to receive messages.
>
> For all these cases, remove this registration token from the app server and stop using it to send messages.

What is the solution to this problem. what should I do ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Did you checked the bundle identifier is right,And Google plist is right for this project.

Comment: Yes, I checked. I'm sure the app information is correct.