# iOS FCM token issue "NotRegistered"

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to call the API "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" using my server key to send an FCM to a specific token. However, I am encountering an issue with the following response.

Request:

```
{
    "to": "<MY TOKEN>",
    "data": {
        "body": "Test Notification !!!",
        "title": "Test Title !!!"
    },
    "notification": {
        "body": "Testing notification",
        "title": "Amit Kava"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6556246662850074558,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "NotRegistered"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you check on app side, firebase is initializing properly and getting correct token from firebase?

Comment: Checked, initialized properly.

Comment: did you requested permission for ios device ? without it will not generate any token : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client

Comment: The error message says that the value you are passing is not registered as an FCM token in the project. Make sure you use the value you get back from [`getToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client#access_the_registration_token) and that your client and server-side code are connected to the same project.

Comment: @HardikMehta Permission is given still it showing error, As per knowledge if permission is not given then notification will not but api give success.

Comment: @AmitKava : token generation may need that permission

Comment: @HardikMehta It's already given. Without it, I can not able to create a token.

Comment: @AmitKava : Please do check this once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77493709/flutter-firebasemessaging-token-not-registered-error